How to Safely Control two Linear Actuators Using Both a Microcontroller and an RF Receiver?
I recently bought a kit that includes a couple of linear actuators, a power supply, a control box, and a remote. Currently, the actuators can only be operated using the included remote.

I’m considering expanding the system to include both manual and Wi-Fi control via an ESP32. I found this helpful article: https://www.progressiveautomations.com/blogs/how-to/how-to-use-relays-to-control-linear-actuators. The guide seems perfect if I wanted to completely replace the RF receiver and integrate the microcontroller instead.
However, I’d like to keep the original remote functionality while also adding ESP32-based control. To achieve this, I came up with the following modified connection diagram (apologies for the lack of a proper schematic):

Now, I believe there’s a significant issue with this setup: if either control method activates one of the relays, the power supply could get shorted.
Here’s my question: can I use diodes to prevent current from flowing back into the other control section? Would this approach be feasible? I’ve checked some datasheets, and since the power supply is rated for 2A, I was thinking of using 1N5822 diodes. Would these work if properly placed?
Thanks for your help!

a: instead of doubling up the relays, connect the receiver to the microcontroller and have the microcontroller repeat the received commands to the relays.
b: connect the receiver and the microcontroller to the same relays using diode logic to resolve any conflicts.

Here’s my question: can I use diodes to prevent current from flowing back into the other control section? Would this approach be feasible? I’ve checked some datasheets, and since the power supply is rated for 2A, I was thinking of using 1N5822 diodes. Would these work if properly placed?

you can't do that with diodes in the supply or motor circuits
but you can put diodes in the command wires.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
or use gates

simulate this circuit

Understood. Thanks. Now I need to hack the stock control box and find out where to hook things... ;)

I've controlled my ceiling fan with a 433MHz transmitter module and an Arduino.  That project I believe is similar to what your trying to accomplish.
Check out this link https://github.com/sui77/rc-switch.
I first used a 433MHz receiver module & Arduino to pickup the data transmission signal from the remote control and decoded the bit stream.  Then used the RC transmitter module & Arduino to transmit the signal.
